# Компонент webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser

Можно ли обновить компонент webbrowser в vb.net

Comment: Вот блин это плохо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyWebBrowser.Refresh()
```

Comment: А как это провернуть

Comment: Вернул в ответ, пожалуйста, сразу задавайте вопросы именно о том, что хотите узнать.

Comment: Извини за дибильный вопрос это обновление страницы или вообще сомого компонента до более новой версии

Comment: Вопрос реально дебильный, и в комментарии и сам вопрос.

Что Вам нужно то? Обновить библиотеку или содержимое объекта на форме?

Comment: Нужно обновить библиотеку

Comment: Программно или... в общем, зачем Вам это нужно?

Comment: Хочу написать браузер на vb.net на при переходе на сайт пишет что у вас старый браузер

Comment: Это Вам не поможет.